# Convert reading of delimited file from F# to C#

Tags: c#, csv, f#, f#-data

I know this is a rather thick question but I am attempting to perform some comparisons between F# and C# and have borrowed an F# script from http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Nearest-Neighbor-Classification-part-2.aspx and am trying to get the equivilant operation out of a C# program for the purpose of testing operation and syntax. This part is in a larger script that I am converting to an F# program that performs a k-means analysis of given data.

Here is the F# portion:

```
let elections =
    let file = @"C:\Users\Deines\Documents\Election2008.txt"
    let fileAsLines =
        File.ReadAllLines(file)
            |> Array.map (fun line -> line.Split(','))
    let dataset =
        fileAsLines
        |> Array.map (fun line ->
            [| Convert.ToDouble(line.[1]);
               Convert.ToDouble(line.[2]);
               Convert.ToDouble(line.[3]) |])
    let labels = fileAsLines |> Array.map (fun line -> line.[4])
    dataset, labels
```

Here is a sample of the data (Election2008.txt):

```
AL,32.7990,-86.8073,4447100,REP 
AK,61.3850,-152.2683,626932,REP 
AZ,33.7712,-111.3877,5130632,REP 
AR,34.9513,-92.3809,2673400,REP 
CA,36.1700,-119.7462,33871648,DEM 
CO,39.0646,-105.3272,4301261,DEM 
CT,41.5834,-72.7622,3405565,DEM 
DE,39.3498,-75.5148,783600,DEM 
DC,38.8964,-77.0262,572059,DEM 
FL,27.8333,-81.7170,15982378,DEM
```

Comment: Please [familiarize yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with how this site operates.  We are not here to perform generalized code translation services.

Comment: If you are going to be using this kind of data often, look into F# Type Providers. There is one specifically for CSV data. It can parse the input data, analyze it, and generate types for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perform the same basic operation in C# via:

```
Tuple<double[][], string[]> GetElections()
{
    var file = @"C:\Users\Deines\Documents\Election2008.txt";
    var fileAsLines = File.ReadLines(file).Select(line => line.Split(','));
    var dataset = fileAsLines.Select(line => new[] 
                                             { 
                                                 Convert.ToDouble(line[1]),
                                                 Convert.ToDouble(line[2]),
                                                 Convert.ToDouble(line[3])
                                             }).ToArray();
    var labels = fileAsLines.Select(line => line[4]).ToArray();
    return Tuple.Create(dataset, labels);
}
```

That being said, C# developers would rarely write this in this manner.  It would be more likely that you'd make a custom type to hold the results (with name + values), and read it that way, ie:

```
class ElectionResult
{
     public ElecationResult(string label, double x, double y, int amount)
     {
         this.Label = label;
         this.Point = new Point(x,y);
         this.Amount = amount;
     }
     string Label { get; private set; }
     Point Location { get; private set; }
     int Amount { get; private set; }
}

IList<ElectionResult> GetElectionResults()
{
    var file = @"C:\Users\Deines\Documents\Election2008.txt";
    var fileAsLines = File.ReadLines(file).Select(line => line.Split(','));

    return fileAsLines.Select(line => new ElectionResult(line[4],
                                                 Convert.ToDouble(line[1]),
                                                 Convert.ToDouble(line[2]),
                                                 Convert.ToInt32(line[3]))
                      .ToList();
}
```

This makes it far more usable for a typical C# developer, as there's no pattern matching to extract the arrays from the Tuple result.

Comment: You are great, thank you this is what I was looking for. I will run this in my test and see how we go.

Comment: Ah, you beat me. The labels select may need to be a SelectMany though.

Comment: @AlexBeisley It shouldn't - it's one label per line...

Comment: You could actually chain each line in a nested `Select` if you wanted it to resemble the structure of the functional implementation.  Not a criticism, just observation.

Comment: @user2930378 I also edited to show a more typical "C# approach", as the direct translation is not very common C# style...

Comment: This mirrors the F# version; either could chain more if they wanted. And yeah, I think you're right about the select.

Comment: @AaronLS I believe this is a pretty close match to the original (except that I'm using the equivelent of `Seq` instead of `Array` for the mappings)

Comment: Personally, I'd use a `struct` with public fields here - much less boilerplate, and the initialization is more readable to boot.  For small things like this, the ability to copy is quite nice, and for plain value amalgamations value semantics are nice too.  But in any case - fields over properties.

Comment: Oh, and might consider `enum {DEM, REP, ...}` too

Comment: @EamonNerbonne Any reason why you prefer fields over properties?  I'm almost completely the opposite, especially if you ever might use in a data binding scenario...  (I do agree with the enum, especially if there are a fixed, known set of potential labels)

Comment: Because it's instantly obvious from the intellisense that there cannot be side-effects; they're faster & have less boilerplate.  Having said that, there are many cases where you cannot use them - such as interfaces and data-binding or when they're non-trivial - but most code is internal, and not data-bound (at least IME).  Basically: they're just slightly simpler all around, and why not keep it simple if you can?

Comment: @ReedCopsey - It's not a big deal to me, but it's particularly noticable in such otherwise trivial code.  Related is that I also like it when people define feel free to define trivial structs (or classes) for passing values around - not methods with millions of parameters, and particularly not with optional parameters, and putting speed-bumps in the way of that encourages poor API design.  But again, it's not a biggie - you could write a trivial data-container even if it had props, it's just a bit more code.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne They shouldn't be faster (post-JIT), though there is less typing boiler plate.  That being said, in this case, this type violates more than half of the rules for choosing structs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40684/discussion-between-eamon-nerbonne-and-reed-copsey)

Comment: but seriously, for your own sake, just use F#